# Show a view just once in whole life cycle of an App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a shopping app and on app launch, it shows signup view and once skip button is clicked it navigates to home view. I want to show signup view just once in whole life time of an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding here the code I used to show walkthrough screen only once in the entire application lifecycle. This can be useful to you.

```
   // show walkthough for first time only (first time the app launches after download).
    bool shownFlag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"walkthroughShownOnce"];
    if(!shownFlag){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"walkthroughShownOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        WalkThroughViewController *vc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WalkThroughViewController"];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window setRootViewController:vc];
    }else{
        //if not walkthough go and check other task

    }
```

Comment: @Shikha yes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions